# Firestore Golang CollectionGroup To Delete individual SubCollection Document

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I was able to use the CollectionGroup to access all the subCollection documents (records) that satisfy a condition. Then I was able to iterate in a loop to delete the subCollection documents. The problem, although it works perfectly but is an hack. Is there a better way to delete subcollections in Firestore using Golang?

```
    it := clientdb.CollectionGroup("mychildSubcollection").Where(...mycondition).OrderBy("myfield", firestore.Desc).Documents(context.Background())
for {
    doc, err := it.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        // return err
    }
    
        // Strucure of the doc.Ref is --> &{0xc0000d6788 projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection/JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection/JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp}        

    // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.ID)
    // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Path)
    // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Parent.Path)
    // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Parent.ID)

    path1 := doc.Ref.Parent.Path
    path2 := path1[0: strings.LastIndex(path1, "myparentCollection")]
    path3 := strings.Replace(path1, path2, "", -1)
    clientdb.Collection(path3).Doc(doc.Ref.ID).Delete(context.Background())    // Regular collection command, to delete the subcollection
}
```

At least to make it a less hack, this may also help -> As you see the doc.Ref provides three fields showing the complete path [doc.Ref.Path or doc.Ref.Parent.Path] the subcollection document id (doc.Ref.ID), how to access the middle field in the structure:  "myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection/JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp"

Thanks!

Comment: "*although it works perfectly but is an hack*" - it is not a hack.  That's exactly what you're supposed to do.  There is no simple command to delete everything in a collection or collection group.

Comment: Thanks Doug as always! I thought this was clumsy.     path1 := doc.Ref.Parent.Path
    path2 := path1[0: strings.LastIndex(path1, "myparentCollection")]
    path3 := strings.Replace(path1, path2, "", -1)

Comment: As it is the way to do it, could you put it in an answer and accept it so other community members can benefit from it?

Comment: I did just now. Thanks. fyi-Looks like I cannot accept my own solution.

Comment: Thanks! Ah, well, if it is in the form of an answer, it is already fine.

Answer (score 0):

The above is accepted as solution. The only comment I am adding is that if there is an better way to extract the path for the collection, it will be more generic. As you see I am using the actual collection name [myparentCollection] to extract the path. Works great, but something generic would be better.

```
now := time.Now() // start deleting old ones, even ones that still have one second left to expire.
it := clientdb.CollectionGroup("mychildSubcollection").Where("expireafter", "<", now.Add(-1*time.Second)).OrderBy("myfield", firestore.Desc).Documents(context.Background())
    for {
        doc, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // return err
        }
        
            // Strucure of the doc.Ref is --> &{0xc0000d6788 projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection/JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection/JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp JwvKbuyRTGx5wZaCviCp}        
    
        // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.ID)
        // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Path)
        // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Parent.Path)
        // fmt.Println(doc.Ref.Parent.ID)
    
         // using some logic with strings below to get (extract) the collection path example: myparentCollection/Ki8sr65sKIoZaCviCp/mychildSubcollection, so the delete can use it and delete the particular document under the sub collection.
        path1 := doc.Ref.Parent.Path
        path2 := path1[0: strings.LastIndex(path1, "myparentCollection")]
        path3 := strings.Replace(path1, path2, "", -1)
        clientdb.Collection(path3).Doc(doc.Ref.ID).Delete(context.Background())    // Regular collection command, to delete the subcollection
    }
```